# why hidden field value won't be updated

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Look at this code :

```
        function ToggleMenu() {
            var v = $("#MenuVisibility").val() ;
            if (v == "1") {
                $('#MenuVisibility').val("0");

            }
            else {
                $('#MenuVisibility').val("1");
            }
            v = $("#MenuVisibility").val();
            alert(v);

        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="MenuVisibility" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="Menu">
        <a class="MainMenu" href="#" onclick="OpenCloseMenu()">Fun</a>
        <div id="ExtendedMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat='server' Text="Toggle Menu" OnClientClick="ToggleMenu()" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click for first time , hidden field value sets to 0 , but when I click for second time, it value won't changed to 1 . why ?

Comment: i want to use asp:button

Answer (score 3):

Because when you click your button, your form gets submitted, and the page gets refreshed. Try preventing the form submission:

```
$("#form1").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @user1182970: But the `asp:Button` is inside of the `form`.  If the button in question has no server-side functionality and is purely client-side functional, you really don't want it to be a server-side ASP.NET control.  That would lead to problems exactly like the one you're facing now.

Comment: You can just return false, in the end of your javascript method. That will cause the button event, to NOT fire.

Comment: @karim79 , for your rates , please improve your answer.

Comment: @user1182970 - please improve your feedback. Please read my comment. Please make sure your DOM is ready as I mentioned in a previous comment. Please don't expect magic bullet solutions every time you post a question.

Comment: @user1182970 It is rated up because it is a good answer for the question you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
<input type="button" ID="Button1" value="Toggle Menu" onclick="ToggleMenu()" />
```

Comment: Why? You're not using a server side "OnClick" or anything with it, so why not just use a standard <input>?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to use `asp:button` since the purpose of the button is for client-side processing

Comment: If you are running a code behind then you need a post back or an ajax

Comment: give me an example please , you say me , I should put this my acts in a update panel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do server side code anyway, you might as well put the toggle logic in the click event of the button:

markup:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="MenuVisibility" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (MenuVisibility.Value == 1)
      MenuVisibility.Value = 0;
   else
      MenuVisibility.Value = 1;
}
```

and add button1's onclick="Button1_Click" as well.